# Rails won't create instance variable

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, parameters, instance-variables

Ok so I am building an eBay clone of sorts and I am trying to implement Braintree as the payments processor and I am having serious issues with my orders controller. All of my logic for creating customers in braintree etc. works. The issue I am having is that I can't get the product id to save when creating my orders.

I have nested the routes for my orders resource below my products resource like so:

```
resources :products do
   resources :orders
end
```

Due to the routing I have set up, the parameters that are passed are:

```
{"_method"=>"get", "authenticity_token"=>"", "controller"=>"orders", "action"=>"new", **"product_id"=>"4"}**
```

My product ID gets passed into the new action. My logic is that I can store it in an instance variable and then save it to my order. My controller is as follows:

```
      def new
        if current_user.is_customer?
          @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate(:customer_id => current_user.id)
        else
          @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate()
        end
        console
      end

    def create
      amount = 50 # only set to a whole decimal number with no '.'
      amount_str = "#{amount}.00"
      @product=Product.find_by(params[:product_id])
      nonce = params[:payment_method_nonce]
      render action: :new and return unless nonce
      @order = Order.new
      @order.amount = amount
      @order.user_id = current_user.id
      @order.product_id= @product.id
      if current_user.is_customer?
        result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
          :amount => amount_str,
          :payment_method_nonce => nonce,
          :order_id => @order.id,
          :customer_id => current_user.id,
          :options => {
            :submit_for_settlement => false,
            :store_in_vault_on_success => true,
          },
        )

        if result.success?
          @order.save!
          redirect_to support_product_path(@product), notice: "Success. Orange you glad I've used Braintree to process your payment?!"
        else
          render 'new'
          flash[:alert] = "Something wasn't quite right. #{result.transaction.processor_response_text}"
        end
      else
        result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
            :amount => amount_str,
            :payment_method_nonce => nonce,
            :order_id => @order.id,
            :customer => {
                :id => current_user.id,
                :first_name => current_user.first_name,
                :last_name => current_user.last_name
            },
            :options => {
                :submit_for_settlement => false,
                :store_in_vault_on_success => true,

            }
        )

        if result.success?
          @order.save!
          redirect_to product_path(@product), notice: "Success. Orange you glad I've used Braintree to process your payment?!"
        else
          render 'new'
          flash[:alert] = "Something wasn't quite right. #{result.transaction.processor_response_text}"
        end
      end

  end
```

I have an association for orders and products and I have done a references migration like so:

```
class AddProductsUsersToOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :orders, :product, index: true
    add_foreign_key :orders, :products
    add_reference :orders, :user, index: true
    add_foreign_key :orders, :users
  end
end
```

Order Model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end
```

So the logic works and gets created however it saves the product_id as the first product in my database and redirects to it regardless of which product I try to order. I have spent hours on this any help is appreciated.

Comment: Of course, product with id of 4 isn't the first one in your database? What's the source of your `Order` class? maybe it has some `before_save`?

Comment: Thank you for reading but Yes, that is the problem! I want it to save product 4 ( or whatever product is in my `params[:product_id]` as the product for the order but it saves product 1!

Comment: As I wrote - maybe problem is with your `Order` model? Could you provide its source?

Comment: Sorry I did but forgot to format. Should be there now. Thanks again!

Comment: So it's not `Order`. You should debug it and check when does this value change. And if it's already changed when you call `@order.save!`.

Comment: Well I wrote a debug on the `orders#new` view and it either comes up nil or changes there but I just can't figure out why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78507/discussion-between-chiefrockachris-and-marek-lipka).